# AngularJS $http.get php file - $injector:modulerr

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have this file api.php

```
require_once 'db.php';
$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
$dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName") or die(mysql_error());
$arr[];
while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
    array_push($arr, $obj);
}

echo $json_response = json_encode($arr);
```

It is grabbing all the data that i need.

Then i am trying to put that data into my $scope here...

```
// The controller
function InstantSearchController($scope, $http){
 $http.get('api.php').success(function(data) {
     $scope.items = data;
     $scope.items = [
          image : data['icon'],
          english : data['english'],
          british : data['british']
     ];
 });
}
```

But this does work if I hard code the data like this.

```
function InstantSearchController($scope){
  $scope.items = [
    {
      english: 'English A',
      british: 'British A',
      image: 'images/advil.jpg'
    },
    {
      english: 'English B',
      british: 'British B',
      image: 'images/advil.jpg'
    }
    ]
}
```

This is the error that i am seeing in the console

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : js/angular.js:44
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=instantSearch&p1=E…larjs.org%2F1.2.15%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DinstantSearch%0A%20%20%20%......1)

This is the fiddle trying response #1

http://jsfiddle.net/XgsWU/

And this one is for response #2

http://jsfiddle.net/JGjyS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone that might be reading this later I figured out my issues was in my controller call and i have changed/updated to this and it is working great!

```
app.controller('InstantSearchController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
     $http.get('inc/api.php').success(function(itemData) {
     $scope.items = itemData;
   });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unexpected token `:`.  This is from:

```
$scope.items = [
      image : data['icon'],
```

You should use `$scope.items = {...}` since you want a JavaScript object with key-value pairs, not an array.

It seems like you also want to loop over `data` and push items onto the array:

```
$scope.items = [];
data.forEach(function (datum) {
    $scope.items.push({
        image: datum.icon,
        english: datum.english,
        british: datbum.british,
    });
});
```

Comment: I am sorry i am not exactly following you here... The below response seem to get ride of the error but isn't working 100% yet. Changing my code to what you provided didn't get ride of the error or change the output. Any other suggestions? Really appreciate the response!

Comment: @Travis perhaps you can set up a jsfiddle to play wiht?

Comment: Honestly didnt know that i could use a fiddle for this but yes i will give it a try right now!

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error here:

```
$scope.items = [
      image : data['icon'],
      english : data['english'],
      british : data['british']
 ];
```

It should be:

```
$scope.items = [
      {image : data['icon'],
      english : data['english'],
      british : data['british']}
 ];
```

Comment: Awesome that had gotten ride of the error now, wasnt populating anything with data['icon'], so switched it to data[1], and now it is populating in each field 

{"id":"4","icon":"advil.jpg","english":"ASS+C 1A-Pharma","british":"Abelitan"}

Any way to update that?